# how to remove the empty title headers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios7

I am having a table view, in that I am having title headers, they are working well, but the sum of the title header values are getting null, I want to hide that null title header in my table view. how can I do this process. please help me in coding.[image]

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [reverseOrder1 objectAtIndex:section];
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return 60;
}
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 75)];
UILabel *headerTitile =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, -5, tableView.bounds.size.width-20, 75)];
headerTitile.text = [reverseOrder1 objectAtIndex:section];

headerTitile.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
headerTitile.TextAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[headerView addSubview:headerTitile];
headerTitile.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16.0f];

headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:48/255.0f green:119/255.0f blue:21/255.0f alpha:1];
return headerView;
}
```

I am getting like above image,i ant to hide the null value title headers.

Comment: you could check if it null set tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: return 0 also tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in `heightForHeaderInSection` is return 0 if no objects

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   //Note use your main array which defines section's row and according to each section it may be dictionary or array use accordingly
   NSArray *arrObjects = yourSectionsRowData[section];
   if([arrObjects count]>0])
      return 60.0;
   else
      return 0.0;
}
```

Also return view nil if not found any objects in `viewForHeaderInSection`

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   //Note use your main array which defines section's row and according to each section it may be dictionary or array use accordingly
   NSArray *arrObjects = yourSectionsRowData[section];
   if([arrObjects count]>0])
      return nil;
   else
   {
      UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 75)];
      UILabel *headerTitile =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, -5, tableView.bounds.size.width-20, 75)];
      headerTitile.text = [reverseOrder1 objectAtIndex:section];

      headerTitile.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
      headerTitile.TextAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
      [headerView addSubview:headerTitile];
      headerTitile.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16.0f];

      headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:48/255.0f green:119/255.0f blue:21/255.0f alpha:1];
      return headerView;
   }
}
```

Comment: yourTablViewDataSourceArray means what

Comment: error ([__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds for empty array')

Comment: error ('NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a88970')

Comment: Use your tableview datasource array and not section title array