# mutable array value getting empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, for-loop, nsarray

I am having an array which contains a date. this is my array.

```
"2015-03-01",
"2015-03-04",
"2015-03-05",
"2015-03-06",
"2015-03-07",
"2015-03-08",
"2015-03-14",
"2015-03-15"
```

list the value according to this date.my coding is

```
NSArray * datevalue = [tempArr valueForKey:@"match_formatted_date"];
                NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
                NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject: descriptor];
                NSArray *reverseOrder = [datevalue sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

 NSPredicate *findFutureDates = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock: ^BOOL(id obj, NSDictionary *bind){
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
                    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
                    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
                    NSDate *dd = [df dateFromString:(NSString *)obj ];
                    return ([[NSDate date] compare:dd] == NSOrderedAscending);
    }];

NSArray * arrFutureDates = [reverseOrder filteredArrayUsingPredicate: findFutureDates];
                NSLog(@"arrFutureDates:%@",arrFutureDates);

for (id item in arrFutureDates)
{
if (![dataArr containsObject:item])
                        [dataArr addObject:item];
}

 [dataArr sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

for  (int i= 0; i<[dataArr count]-1; i++)  {

                    for (id item in tempArr)
{
if([@"Mexico: Copa Mexico - Clausura" isEqualToString:[item valueForKey:@"league_name"]]
                           ||[@"Mexico: Liga De Ascenso - Clausura" isEqualToString:[item valueForKey:@"league_name"]]
                           ||[@"Mexico: Primera Division - Clausura" isEqualToString:[item valueForKey:@"league_name"]])

                           if([[dataArr objectAtIndex:i]isEqualToString:[item valueForKey:@"match_formatted_date"]])
{
NSMutableDictionary *tempDic =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                                [tempDic setValue: [item valueForKey:@"match_formatted_date"]  forKey:@"match_formatted_date"];
                                [tempDic setValue: [item valueForKey:@"league_name"]  forKey:@"league_name"];



if (![titleheader containsObject:tempDic])

{
[titleheader addObject:tempDic];
}}}}
```

my problem is: In title header null value is coming. were I made the mistake, can anyone help me.

Comment: you alloc array in your `-(void)viewdidload` method?

Comment: yes, it is in viewdidload

Comment: okh then check RJV Kumar answer.

Comment: Add your viewDidLoad method body here too

Answer (score 0):

Check your code, you didnt initialize titleheader anywhere. In that case it will be nil only. 
Before checking condition, initialize and assign some value to titleheader.
Or else i dont know you missed to paste the code.

Comment: i have initialize the title header as mutable array in .h file,ya i missed to paste the code

Answer (score 0):

Unreadable formatting aside, there are few issues in your code, that may cause your problem:

```
NSArray* datevalue = [tempArr valueForKey:@"match_formatted_date"];
```

Name suggests, that `tempArr` is `NSArray`, however you are accessing it as `NSDictionary`. There is difference between methods `-valueForKey:` and `-objectForKey:`. Former is `NSObject` method related to KVC, while latter is `NSDictionary` method for accessing stored objects. They are frequently confused, because called on `NSDictionary` they behave in the same way.

```
for  (int i= 0; i<[dataArr count]-1; i++)  {
```

This `for` loop skips last object in `dataArr`, which - I assume - was not intended. This can be fixed by `i < dataArr.count` or `i <= dataArr.count-1`.

Another issue - not related to problem, but opportunity to learn:

```
NSMutableDictionary *tempDic =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                            [tempDic setValue: [item valueForKey:@"match_formatted_date"]  forKey:@"match_formatted_date"];
                            [tempDic setValue: [item valueForKey:@"league_name"]  forKey:@"league_name"];


if (![titleheader containsObject:tempDic])
```

Objects in containers are stored and compared (by default) as references, thus `-containsObject` will always return `NO` - even if there were another `NSDictionary` with the same key-value pairs.

Comment: thanks bro, i will correct my mistake. still my title header get empty value

Comment: Can you post how your dataArr, tempArr and titleheader are initialized?

Comment: dataarr is the above date array , temparr is too big all of them are initialized.what can i do now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739599/how-to-remove-the-empty-title-headers    (can u help me for this question)